# Best Processor for WiFi to GbE Bridge

Tags: microcontroller, ethernet, wifi

I’m looking to build a WiFi to Ethernet Bridge, and did an initial test with a Raspberry Pi 4B. I noticed the CPU was always using less than 10% processing power, which makes me question whether or not I need a full Linux computer for such a computationally simple task.

I realize there are many types of processors out there (FPGA, MCU, MPU, DSP, etc.) is there one best suited to handle the high data/low calculation process of a WiFi to Ethernet Bridge?

Comment: This is similar to the question you asked some time ago. Something like an Onion Omega2 board solves your problem. Hop ontoAliExpress and there’s a zillion similar wireless router chip based boards that run OpenWrt.

Comment: Oh wow ok thanks! I’ll do some research on OpenWrt, haven’t heard of it before.

Comment: Looks like most Onion modules have 10/100M Ethernet, have you heard of any that allow for 1000M?

Comment: Look for MT7621 based boards and I think there’s a Qualcomm QCxxxx based device as well. We went through this last time you asked the question. Make Google and ChatGPT your friend.

Comment: Haha yeah we had this discussion last time. Problem with those vendors is that they only supply to larger companies. Looking at NXP or TI for the most part

Comment: Do you really want to design your own board? Find a supplier onAliExpress and have them do a custom board for you. There will be a MOQ I expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux is actually a good choice. Consider that many routers and similar devices run some form of Linux or can be [modified to run DD-WRT](https://dd-wrt.com/).

This is also not a "computationally simple task". To me that might mean something you could run on a 4 Mhz Z-80. The Raspberry Pi 4B has a 1.8 Ghz 64-bit processor - 10% of that is equivalent to a **lot** of Z-80s. Plus you would not want a system where you have to run at even 50% of CPU capacity. It might mean you could back down to a Raspberry Pi 1 or similar and run at perhaps 20% - 40%.

What you don't need are the "extras" that make the difference between a bare-bones system and a Raspberry Pi 4B. All you really need are:

- CPU
- RAM
- ROM (of some sort - flash memory, etc.)
- WiFi
- Ethernet
- Power Supply

Anything else is superfluous. So you don't need:

- USB ports (except one can be a convenient way to supply power)
- HDMI ports
- Expansion bus

And if you then manufacture it in large quantities, you get a very low cost per unit. If you are only building a few, a Raspberry Pi that includes HDMI, USB, etc. may be worth the extra few $ as the extra hardware can make development a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer! I’ve basically designed out what you’ve described in bullets, but am wondering if using some type of high-power MCU with custom firmware would be more affordable.  Is going this route even possible, or is an MCU really not powerful enough to handle this task?

Comment: Also, what is a Z-80?

Comment: Hard to say. WiFi is really quite complex - encryption and lots of other good stuff. But really it comes down to quantity. If you are building 1 or 2, use a Pi 4B and be done. If you are building 10 or 20, use a Pi 1 or 2 or similar so that you have a very similar environment (so you can develop on the 4B and go to production on the 1 or 2) but a slightly lower cost. If you are building 100 then the equation changes a bit.

Comment: A Z-80 is a classic 8-bit CPU. Very popular from late 1970s through the 1980s - TRS-80 1/2/3, lots of CP/M machines, etc. (main competition for 8-bit desktop computers was the 6502, and lots of 6502s got Z-80s too - e.g., enabling Apple ][ to run CP/M), plus a lot of embedded systems - print buffers, multiplexers, modems, industrial controllers, etc.

Comment: Makes sense. If end goal is in the 1000s, I’m guessing the Linux-based device will become cheap enough to justify its use over maxing out something less powerful like a MCU. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Linux doesn't get cheaper in the 1000s. What changes though is that then you can find and/or get custom manufactured devices that don't include HDMI, USB (except power), etc. that include only as much RAM as is needed, etc.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact you really should have a management port, either USB or serial

Comment: @jsotola A separate management port is ideal. And could be Ethernet rather than USB or serial. But not a requirement. Plenty of devices use the same Ethernet port for management as for in-use communication, with (sometimes) a switch to change modes so that if you have a bricked device or lost passwords, etc. but have physical access (which you would need for USB or serial access too) that you can get into it.